# avoid .net XmlTextWriter escaping ampersand in front of character reference

Tags: c#, xml, xmlwriter

Can someone please be explain why System.Xml.XmlTextWriter escapes the ampersand in front of what I thought was a valid unicode character reference:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestEncoding()
{
    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        XmlWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
        const string testChar = "&#8211;";
        writer.WriteString(testChar);
        Assert.AreEqual(testChar, sw.ToString());
        writer.Close();
    }
}
```

fails with the message

```
Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<&#8211;>. Actual:<&amp;#8211;>.
```

Is there a way to escape this behavior, while correctly maintaining conversion of isolated or invalid ampersands to &amp; ?

#### Edit

the answer by wdosanjos made me realise how to achieve what I was after (cleaning up html character encoding before being stored as xml - the resultant string is not used by html browsers, so replacing &nbsp; with [space] does not matter in the use scenario here:

```
html = Regex.Replace(html, @"&#?x?[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,7};", ReplaceCharEntities);
...
private static string ReplaceCharEntities(Match m)
{
    string s= m.ToString();
    s = s.Substring(1,s.Length-2);
    if (s[0] == '#')
    {
        if (s[1]=='x')
        {
            return Char.ConvertFromUtf32(Int32.Parse(s.Substring(2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber));
        }
        return Char.ConvertFromUtf32(Int32.Parse(s.Substring(1)));
    }
    switch (s)
    {
        case "nbsp": return "\u00a0";
        case "iexcl": return "\u00a1";
        case "cent": return "\u00a2";
        case "pound": return "\u00a3";
        case "curren": return "\u00a4";
        case "yen": return "\u00a5";
        case "brvbar": return "\u00a6";
        case "sect": return "\u00a7";
        case "uml": return "\u00a8";
        case "copy": return "\u00a9";
        case "ordf": return "\u00aa";
        case "laquo": return "\u00ab";
        case "not": return "\u00ac";
        case "shy": return "\u00ad";
        case "reg": return "\u00ae";
        case "macr": return "\u00af";
        case "deg": return "\u00b0";
        case "plusmn": return "\u00b1";
        case "sup2": return "\u00b2";
        case "sup3": return "\u00b3";
        case "acute": return "\u00b4";
        case "micro": return "\u00b5";
        case "para": return "\u00b6";
        case "middot": return "\u00b7";
        case "cedil": return "\u00b8";
        case "sup1": return "\u00b9";
        case "ordm": return "\u00ba";
        case "raquo": return "\u00bb";
        case "frac14": return "\u00bc";
        case "frac12": return "\u00bd";
        case "frac34": return "\u00be";
        case "iquest": return "\u00bf";
        case "Agrave": return "\u00c0";
        case "Aacute": return "\u00c1";
        case "Acirc": return "\u00c2";
        case "Atilde": return "\u00c3";
        case "Auml": return "\u00c4";
        case "Aring": return "\u00c5";
        case "AElig": return "\u00c6";
        case "Ccedil": return "\u00c7";
        case "Egrave": return "\u00c8";
        case "Eacute": return "\u00c9";
        case "Ecirc": return "\u00ca";
        case "Euml": return "\u00cb";
        case "Igrave": return "\u00cc";
        case "Iacute": return "\u00cd";
        case "Icirc": return "\u00ce";
        case "Iuml": return "\u00cf";
        case "ETH": return "\u00d0";
        case "Ntilde": return "\u00d1";
        case "Ograve": return "\u00d2";
        case "Oacute": return "\u00d3";
        case "Ocirc": return "\u00d4";
        case "Otilde": return "\u00d5";
        case "Ouml": return "\u00d6";
        case "times": return "\u00d7";
        case "Oslash": return "\u00d8";
        case "Ugrave": return "\u00d9";
        case "Uacute": return "\u00da";
        case "Ucirc": return "\u00db";
        case "Uuml": return "\u00dc";
        case "Yacute": return "\u00dd";
        case "THORN": return "\u00de";
        case "szlig": return "\u00df";
        case "agrave": return "\u00e0";
        case "aacute": return "\u00e1";
        case "acirc": return "\u00e2";
        case "atilde": return "\u00e3";
        case "auml": return "\u00e4";
        case "aring": return "\u00e5";
        case "aelig": return "\u00e6";
        case "ccedil": return "\u00e7";
        case "egrave": return "\u00e8";
        case "eacute": return "\u00e9";
        case "ecirc": return "\u00ea";
        case "euml": return "\u00eb";
        case "igrave": return "\u00ec";
        case "iacute": return "\u00ed";
        case "icirc": return "\u00ee";
        case "iuml": return "\u00ef";
        case "eth": return "\u00f0";
        case "ntilde": return "\u00f1";
        case "ograve": return "\u00f2";
        case "oacute": return "\u00f3";
        case "ocirc": return "\u00f4";
        case "otilde": return "\u00f5";
        case "ouml": return "\u00f6";
        case "divide": return "\u00f7";
        case "oslash": return "\u00f8";
        case "ugrave": return "\u00f9";
        case "uacute": return "\u00fa";
        case "ucirc": return "\u00fb";
        case "uuml": return "\u00fc";
        case "yacute": return "\u00fd";
        case "thorn": return "\u00fe";
        case "yuml": return "\u00ff";
        case "Alpha": return "\u0391";
        case "Beta": return "\u0392";
        case "Gamma": return "\u0393";
        case "Delta": return "\u0394";
        case "Epsilon": return "\u0395";
        case "Zeta": return "\u0396";
        case "Eta": return "\u0397";
        case "Theta": return "\u0398";
        case "Iota": return "\u0399";
        case "Kappa": return "\u039a";
        case "Lambda": return "\u039b";
        case "Mu": return "\u039c";
        case "Nu": return "\u039d";
        case "Xi": return "\u039e";
        case "Omicron": return "\u039f";
        case "Pi": return "\u03a0";
        case "Rho": return "\u03a1";
        case "Sigma": return "\u03a3";
        case "Tau": return "\u03a4";
        case "Upsilon": return "\u03a5";
        case "Phi": return "\u03a6";
        case "Chi": return "\u03a7";
        case "Psi": return "\u03a8";
        case "Omega": return "\u03a9";
        case "alpha": return "\u03b1";
        case "beta": return "\u03b2";
        case "gamma": return "\u03b3";
        case "delta": return "\u03b4";
        case "epsilon": return "\u03b5";
        case "zeta": return "\u03b6";
        case "eta": return "\u03b7";
        case "theta": return "\u03b8";
        case "iota": return "\u03b9";
        case "kappa": return "\u03ba";
        case "lambda": return "\u03bb";
        case "mu": return "\u03bc";
        case "nu": return "\u03bd";
        case "xi": return "\u03be";
        case "omicron": return "\u03bf";
        case "pi": return "\u03c0";
        case "rho": return "\u03c1";
        case "sigmaf": return "\u03c2";
        case "sigma": return "\u03c3";
        case "tau": return "\u03c4";
        case "upsilon": return "\u03c5";
        case "phi": return "\u03c6";
        case "chi": return "\u03c7";
        case "psi": return "\u03c8";
        case "omega": return "\u03c9";
        case "&thetasym;": return "\u03d1";
        case "upsih": return "\u03d2";
        case "piv": return "\u03d6";
        case "bull": return "\u2022";
        case "hellip": return "\u2026";
        case "prime": return "\u2032";
        case "Prime": return "\u2033";
        case "oline": return "\u203e";
        case "frasl": return "\u2044";
        case "weierp": return "\u2118";
        case "image": return "\u2111";
        case "real": return "\u211c";
        case "trade": return "\u2122";
        case "alefsym": return "\u2135";
        case "larr": return "\u2190";
        case "uarr": return "\u2191";
        case "rarr": return "\u2192";
        case "darr": return "\u2193";
        case "harr": return "\u2194";
        case "crarr": return "\u21b5";
        case "lArr": return "\u21d0";
        case "uArr": return "\u21d1";
        case "rArr": return "\u21d2";
        case "dArr": return "\u21d3";
        case "hArr": return "\u21d4";
        case "forall": return "\u2200";
        case "part": return "\u2202";
        case "exist": return "\u2203";
        case "empty": return "\u2205";
        case "nabla": return "\u2207";
        case "isin": return "\u2208";
        case "notin": return "\u2209";
        case "ni": return "\u220b";
        case "prod": return "\u220f";
        case "sum": return "\u2211";
        case "minus": return "\u2212";
        case "lowast": return "\u2217";
        case "radic": return "\u221a";
        case "prop": return "\u221d";
        case "infin": return "\u221e";
        case "ang": return "\u2220";
        case "and": return "\u2227";
        case "or": return "\u2228";
        case "cap": return "\u2229";
        case "cup": return "\u222a";
        case "int": return "\u222b";
        case "there4": return "\u2234";
        case "sim": return "\u223c";
        case "cong": return "\u2245";
        case "asymp": return "\u2248";
        case "ne": return "\u2260";
        case "equiv": return "\u2261";
        case "le": return "\u2264";
        case "ge": return "\u2265";
        case "sub": return "\u2282";
        case "sup": return "\u2283";
        case "nsub": return "\u2284";
        case "sube": return "\u2286";
        case "supe": return "\u2287";
        case "oplus": return "\u2295";
        case "otimes": return "\u2297";
        case "perp": return "\u22a5";
        case "sdot": return "\u22c5";
        case "lceil": return "\u2308";
        case "rceil": return "\u2309";
        case "lfloor": return "\u230a";
        case "rfloor": return "\u230b";
        case "lang": return "\u2329";
        case "rang": return "\u232a";
        case "loz": return "\u25ca";
        case "spades": return "\u2660";
        case "clubs": return "\u2663";
        case "hearts": return "\u2665";
        case "diams": return "\u2666";
        case "OElig": return "\u0152";
        case "oelig": return "\u0153";
        case "Scaron": return "\u0160";
        case "scaron": return "\u0161";
        case "Yuml": return "\u0178";
        case "circ": return "\u02c6";
        case "tilde": return "\u02dc";
        case "ensp": return "\u2002";
        case "emsp": return "\u2003";
        case "thinsp": return "\u2009";
        case "zwnj": return "\u200c";
        case "zwj": return "\u200d";
        case "lrm": return "\u200e";
        case "rlm": return "\u200f";
        case "ndash": return "\u2013";
        case "mdash": return "\u2014";
        case "lsquo": return "\u2018";
        case "rsquo": return "\u2019";
        case "sbquo": return "\u201a";
        case "ldquo": return "\u201c";
        case "rdquo": return "\u201d";
        case "bdquo": return "\u201e";
        case "dagger": return "\u2020";
        case "Dagger": return "\u2021";
        case "permil": return "\u2030";
        case "lsaquo": return "\u2039";
        case "rsaquo": return "\u203a";
        case "euro": return "\u20ac";
        default: return s;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`testchar` just contains the string "&#8211;", which `XmlTextWriter` correctly escapes as `&amp;#8211;`.  You need to set `testChar` escaping the unicode char using C# escaping syntax as follows:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestEncoding()
{
    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        XmlWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
        const string testChar = "\u8211";
        writer.WriteString(testChar);
        Assert.AreEqual(testChar, sw.ToString());
        writer.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution changes both: the string that is written to XML and the string being compared against, so that the behavior of `string` and the behavior of `XmlWriter` are matching. But what if I actually want to write `&#8211;` and not `舑` to XML? There is no solution yet. It always writes `&amp;#8211;`

Comment: this can be done by using `writer.WriteRaw("&#8211;")`.